# Gradually download an image with nsurlsession

Tags: ios, image, nsurlsession, download, downloading-website-files

I'm looking to add a function to my app, through which images can be downloaded from a hosting service. I know how to download it in the usual way, but I wanted to do it in a way so that the image is shown blurred/pixelated at first, and it is gradually sharpened as download progresses. I've seen it in some apps before, but I don't know what to call it/how to implement it.

Any help or direction pointing is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google "Progressive JPEG".

Comment: @zaph so much time wasted until now, and so much saved with your comment! Thanks a bunch.